# How Popup Keyboard After Segue to New Naviagtion Controller Animation Has Finished

Tags: objective-c, ios

I segue from a tableview to detail view controller using custom segues.

```
    @implementation QuickNoteFlipSegue

- (void) perform {

    UIViewController *src = (UIViewController *) self.sourceViewController;
    UIViewController *dst = (UIViewController *) self.destinationViewController;
    dst.navigationItem.hidesBackButton = YES;
    [UIView transitionWithView:src.navigationController.view duration:1.00
                       options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionCurlUp
                    animations:^{
                        [src.navigationController pushViewController:dst animated:NO];
                    }
                    completion:^(BOOL finished){
                        if (finished) {
                                                        }
                    }];


}


@end
```

What I would like to do it when the transition has finished, popup the keyboard for my textview.

I currently do this by calling

> [textView becomeFirstResponder];

This pops up the keyboard OK but before the transition animation has finished. How to detect when the animation has finished before I popup the keyboard?

I should maybe put something is the completion of the animation, but how to make the custom segue aware of the textview in it's destination?

Comment: where u have write this ([textView becomeFirstResponder];) line?

Comment: try putting the code in the `viewDidAppear` method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a method to your `DestinationViewController`:

```
-(void)openKeyboard
{
    [textView becomeFirstResponder];
}
```

Then change your `perform` method:

```
- (void) perform {

    UIViewController *src = (UIViewController *) self.sourceViewController;
    DestinationViewController *dst = (DestinationViewController *) self.destinationViewController;
    dst.navigationItem.hidesBackButton = YES;
    [UIView transitionWithView:src.navigationController.view duration:1.00
                       options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionCurlUp
                    animations:^{
                        [src.navigationController pushViewController:dst animated:NO];
                    }
                    completion:^(BOOL finished){
                        if (finished) {
                            [dst openKeyboard];
                        }
                    }];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Do:

```
-(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];
    [textView becomeFirstResponder];
}
```

Comment: Sorry, forgot to mention I use a custom segue. Question updated